# How to set data for dewplayer dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=File.ashx?Id=SomeID' width="240" height="20" id="dewplayer">
       <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
       <param name="movie" value='dewplayer-vol.swf?mp3=File.ashx?Id=SomeID'/>
</object>
```

In the above code I want to dynamically set the data attribute of object element and value attribute of param name="movie" using javascript with different value for Id every time.

I've already tried the same with predefined values for ID for each file but that causes having multiple players for different files.

All I want is a single player and assign the file to the same player on click.

```
$('div#play').click(function() {
  //Set new new file ID to the player
  //Re-initialize the player with new ID.
  //Play the file
});
```

Any advice on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this Code:

```
    $('div#play').click(function() {
        $('#dewplayer').attr('data', 'http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/SWF/zeldaADPCM2bit.swf');
        $("param[name='movie']").attr('data', 'http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/SWF/zeldaADPCM2bit.swf');
    });
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks iceDragon for your reply.
Modified it and it worked. :)